# Sorting HTML Table that is generated from CSV table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, csv

Hi I am trying to create a sort functionality in an HTML table that is generated from a CSV file. I added in some javascript that supposedly did it but I'm not the best at this. Please advise.

Heres the code I'm using

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>HKJC Football</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cscasiapacific.com/tablesort/jquery-latest.js"> </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cscasiapacific.com/tablesort/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-image: url('http://1080phdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/kick-the-ball-1080p-hd-wallpaper.jpg');
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #000;
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-   width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-  style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
 }
 table, th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
table, th, td {
background-color: green;
color: white;
}
</style><!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]--></head>
</head>
<?php
echo "<html><center><body><table>  
<thead>
<tr> 
</thead></tr><tbody>  \n\n";
$f = fopen("http://www.rittmayer.info/sports/home4/rittmaye/public_html/cscasiapacific/football.CSV",   "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n
</tbody></table>
</body></center></html>";
```

Thanks!

Comment: you haven't asked a question or told us what the problem is

Comment: FYI, you need to close the `<!--` comment tag for your CSS.

Comment: @Dagon I wish to make the table sortable by the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included the javascript files but are not using them in any way. Add this in your HTML. Look for example javascript on how to sort the table on the plugin's homepage.

Tablesorter requires that your table have an ID. `<table id="myTable">`

Then the code necessary to have the tableSorter execute the tablesorter plugin code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
});
</script>
```

Wrapping it in jQuery's `.ready()` method is necessary since you need to wait until PHP is done and the page is fully loaded, otherwise the javascript may fire too early.

Comment: I added this in but the table still appears unsortable? Here is the page in question if that helps.
 http://cscasiapacific.com/test5.php
Sorry for the newbie questions :(

Comment: No, no. Put those two script lines where they were before. Your sort code needs to go in there. Read the documentation for table sorter. There should be some sort of example. You haven't listed where this plugin comes from.

Comment: I'm using something I came across called Table Sorter? 
http://tablesorter.com/docs/
Obviously I don't know how to use it properly. What code needs to go where exactly, I'm a bit confused by this whole thing. Thanks for the patience xD

Comment: also when I put in the sort code it doesn't do anything? What am I doing wrong? D:

Comment: 1.) Change `<table>` to `<table id=#myTable>`. 2.) Move the two scripts above the code in my answer (Like I said, javascript is very picky about the load order). Then I think you might be done.

Comment: Made those changes and the table still appears to be unsortable... Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I've moved all the javascript above your code and added in table headers (Could it be a problem with it being a generated table rather than an existing one?) If so how would I sort that? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, `<table id="myTable">` is the correct format. Keep the rest of the code as-is.

Comment: Changing that made the entire page disappear (or fail to load?) 
http://cscasiapacific.com/test5.php

Comment: Check your PHP. You might need to escape the double quotes with backslash, i.e. \" (since you're using PHP echo to print it to the page).

Comment: I'm sorry but laymans terms please, "escape the double quotes with backslash"?

Comment: @Ludono these are the very basics and I also gave you an example above. If you need it spelled out, this is what I mean: `<table id=\"myTable\">`

Comment: I THINK THAT WORKED. Thank you SO much for bearing with me dude. I'm still very new at this so this help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: @Ludono please make sure to mark my answer as your solution.